# The Horizontal Expander does not include all information from the question

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

In the moderator queue, there's a horizontal expander. It used to display the question in its rendered form (complete with bio box of who asked the question).

It no longer does this. I don't use it often, so I don't know when this broke.

Once you finish expanding, you get whitespace, but never who posted the question (the bio box information).

[image]

Expected Behavior:

The question should be show in its rendered form with all information from the original question (Who asked it, last edit).